# jQuery .each() makes canvas flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I am making a game in JavaScript. Whenever I put a `.each()` in to iterate through a list of bullets or enemies, it makes a small yet noticeable flicker on the screen. would there be any way to fix this?

```
function playing() {
    $.each(bullets, function (index, bullet) { //Makes tiny flicker.
        bullet.update();
    })
}

function update() {
    if (!gameOver) {
        %("menu").hide();
        playing();
    } else {
        $("#menu").show();
    }

    setTimeout(update(), 6);
}

spawnE(); //spawns enemy
update();
```

NOTE: I am using `setTimeout()` instead of `requestAnimationFrame()` because it keeps the speed of the game consistent across different refresh rates.

Comment: The problem might not be there. Need more context to this

Comment: This might be more than what you can programmatically do, are your bullets images? You could try compressing the images if they're jpg/png or use something much more lightweight like an SVG. They could be anything though (divs) we need more context!

Comment: The problem is most likey within the `update` method. Can you update your question with the `update` code?

Comment: Have you made any progress? If not can you provide a demo (jsFiddle, Codepen)?

Comment: `setTimeout(update(), 6);` should be `setTimeout(update, 6);`, no? The original version calls it immediately, then passes `undefined` to be scheduled by the `setTimeout`. Also, probably better to use `setInterval` than repeated `setTimeout`, and you can keep speed consistent with `requestAnimationFrame` using time. Functions should be verbs, not present progressive (or whatever linguistic syntax this is...), e.g. `play()` rather than `playing()`. I want to tell my program to play, not tell it to playing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. JQuery's `.each()` is just slower than vanilla javascript's     `.forEach()` due to it being a large library.